# How to keep data/tables stored in Mathematica notebooks for use when reopening the notebook?

Tags: dataset, table

When we create a table in Mathematica, can we keep it stored in the Noteboook for use when we reopen the notebook? I know I can export to a CSV or other filetypes and import whenever I need and I know that we can store data when we use Datasets with the button:

> [image]

But once I reopen the notebook, I see only the table provided by the Dataset, I don't know how to actually use the data in there for other computations. I read some questions which seemed to deal with the question I am asking but none of them actually seemed to be about what I am asking about.

Comment: IN MMA version 13.2 there is: `PersistentSymbol`   Look it up in the help.

Comment: I think that this is a good question that should not be closed. It is not about programming, it is about the UI. When you click "store now", by default you don't know where did it go and how to reuse it. I do know this, but that is not the point.